# How to use api in DRF with authentication in python

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I want to make an API with token Authentication.
Now i can use Postman But in other hand i don't know how can i used it in python.

I tried this into python:

```py
import requests
response = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/get-all-data/ 'Authorization: Token f468db88cb3b4e92ba00f662a4f334d47bd27f38'")


print(response.json())
```

but it gives me an error:
`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
response = requests.get(
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/get-all-data/",
    headers={'Authorization': 'Token f468db88cb3b4e92ba00f662a4f334d47bd27f38'}
)
```

The header should be set as a kwargs of `headers`. If it still fails, check if it gives you any information from `response.text`